# Python- Error in playing mp3 audio using vlc-command line

Tags: python, audio, command-line, vlc

**Objective**

I wanted to use the os module to play an audio file using VLC player at a faster rate.

`os.system("vlc 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.mp3' --rate=1.5")`

**What should have happened**

A VLC player window should have popped open and the music should have started playing at a speed 1.5 times that of the default speed.

**What happened instead**

File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.mp3'". (%m)
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///C:/Program%20Files/VideoLAN/VLC/%27C%3A/Users/user/Desktop/file1.mp3%27'. Check the log for details.

**Code**

`import os
os.chdir("C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC")
os.system("vlc 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.mp3' --rate=1.5")`

Where did I go wrong?

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 2.7 you may also use the following.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(r'vlc --rate 5 C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.mp3',shell = True)
```

AFAIK, the rate switch should be given immediately after vlc. This worked for me

Please let me know if it solved your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the [extra quoting required in Windows paths](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/)

If you are using Python >=3.5 you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) instead of `os.system` which could help with the quoting issues as well.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['vlc', r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.mp3',
                '--play-and-exit', '--rate=1.5'])
```